# Azure DevOps: How do I add interactive filters to my dashboard?

Tags: azure-devops, widget, dashboard

I want to filter my dashboard content by month and different teams working on requests. Could you please suggest a way to add interactive filter in Azure DevOps?

I have explored different widgets available to us in Marketplace and the concept of dashboard extension.